# View items content type as css class in view template

Tags: views, nodes, theming

I have a view which outputs node titles from various content types, what I need is to theme the view template so one of the css classes for each row in my view is the item's content type. How would I do that?

EDIT: I tried to add the code below in the view template file but it doesn't seem to output any code:

```
<ul class="<?php print $fields['type']->content ?>">
```

In fact I even tried outputting it as a regular field but it simply seems to be ignored:

```
<?php print $fields['type']->content ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust the template (tpl) file that's being used to generate the markup for the Views output. I think everything you'll need as well as a bunch of related and equally important info can be found here: Mustardseed -> [Views Theming](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode23)

Comment: OK problem solved, I think in addition to my other problems, my view was a little buggy but it seems to be working now. I'll go with your answer, because watching a couple of mustard seed's videos really gave me insight into theming  rows -- thanks!